# Can i Monitor iptables on Monitoring system

Tags: centos, monitoring, iptables, prtg, solarwindslem

I have a Centos server and I install iptables on this for firewall.
I want to connect iptables to monitoring system Like (Prtg,Solarwinds,Opmanger) 
Is this possible?

Comment: you haven't written what you want to monitor

Comment: Per connection ,ip,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**

I don't know what other monitoring systems, but you can do that with [Solarwinds Server Application Monitor](https://www.solarwinds.com/server-application-monitor), by creating custom [LinuxScript](https://support.solarwinds.com/Success_Center/Server_Application_Monitor_(SAM)/SAM_Administrator_Guide/0L0_Manage_application_monitor_templates_and_component_monitors/0D0_Creating_a_Linux_Unix_Script_monitor) component. You can find an example in [thwack forum](https://thwack.solarwinds.com/docs/DOC-188374)